# The two consecutive elements converted into single element using docbook to dita

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook, dita

My Input docbook xml having the below tags:

```
<section><title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
<section><para>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</para>
</section></section>
```

I want the output element as

```
<section>
<title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
<p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
    a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
    (BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>
</section>
```

How i can change the `<section><para>` into a `<p>` element by using XSLT. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="section/section[para]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation then the `para` inside of a `section` nested inside a parent `section` is transformed into a `p` replacing the inner `section`.

So the complete stylesheet is

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section/section[para]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="para">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

which transforms the input

```
<section><title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
<section><para>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</para>
</section></section>
```

into the output

```
<section><title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
<p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>
</section>
```

online at http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAY.

Comment: Hi Martin, While i used the above tag. Im getting the output like this       <section>
         <title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
      </section>
      <p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>
But i want to close the section element after the </p> tag only

Comment: A complete sample with my suggestion is http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAY, it appears to me that the output there is the one you have given above as the wanted result.

Comment: I used <xsl:template match="section">
        <section>       
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::section)]"/>
        </section>
<xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>      
    </xsl:template>
styles in xsl. Is this code will affect that answer. Can you please tell me

Comment: I have made a suggestion on how to solve that in my answer. If you have code not working then you should show it in your question when asking the question or perhaps by editing the question once you can't get something to work, but certainly by posting code in comments. What is wrong with the suggestion I made?

Comment: Your provided code is working only. But the section tag is closed before the <p> tag start. I want to close the </section> tag after the </p> tag. So only i mentioned, that another style having the section element. I just showed you that my expected output getting affected due to that style.

Comment: The code I posted produces the output you said you want in your question. I have edited the answer to show the full stylesheet and the input used and the output I get (which of course has the outer `section` containing the inner `p`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, your code is working fine. Because of my another styles for section only it was not worked properly.